# Export & Import in SQL DEVELOPER without datapump

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to export below things from SQL developer
1-Only schema (tables structure)
2-Only data in excel form
3-Schema with data
after exporting this i want to import the same to the another database
So what steps should i follow for export and import?

I can not use DATA PUMP as i don't have DBA privilege

Comment: There a wizard for doing exports, Excel is an output option. We have a wizard for doing Excel imports, but one file at a time. Better to ask your dba for the privs required to do the job at hand, or ask them to do the exports/imports for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you use Oracle 11g, I'd suggest you to forget about SQL Developer and use the **original** **EXP** and **IMP** utilities. Doing so, you'd avoid *DBA-related-problems* as these utilities don't require access to the directory (an Oracle object which points to (usually database server's) filesystem directory, and - in order to be able to use it - you'd need to have read/write privileges on it).

So - if you don't already have these, install Oracle Client which contains EXP/IMP and use them.